# Ubuntu Installation cancel

Tags: system-installation, windows, 18.10

What will happen if I choose 'Erase Everything and Install' option and then cancel it midway or turn off my PC? Will I be able to get into Windows or will it be erased?

Comment: The same thing that will happen if you interrupt a Windows install or Windows Restore: Your system won't boot anymore, and all your data will have been reformatted into oblivion. Is this a hypothetical question>

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you call 'midway'. I suppose that the installation begins by formatting the disk, so it would at least be difficult to restore Windows' data or restart it.

After formatting data will be copied to the disk so the previous contents will be overwritten at least partially.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in installation after hitting install is the procedures you defined in formatting your disk.

I once cancelled a 'erase everything and install' at the first few seconds and I was fine. I surmise that the installer did not have time to run mkfs in time to wipe my drive.

So you could end up with nothing wrong at all or a corrupted drive/partition that you would need to reformat to be able to use.

If you cancelled it midway, I believe the formatting would have already taken place, but I don't know if the installer would leave the files it was copying over into your drive or if it would clear it out.

I do know that installations that fail about 80% of the way in leave files on the drive for a person to be able to chroot in and diagnose.

On your question about Windows: if this just happened to you, might as well boot into Windows and see what's up. You should have a recovery USB for Windows in cases like these.